# isNewLine new feature in Stanford CoreNLP

Tags: stanford-nlp

I'm the main developer of Tint, a NLP tool for Italian mainly built on Stanford CoreNLP. I'm updating to version 3.9.1 but I noticed that there is a new annotation called `IsNewlineAnnotation`.

As I could not find any documentation about that (and it breaks the other annotators, as the NER needs it), I looked into the source code.
For what I understand, it's a new kind of token (`CoreLabel`) used for marking newlines. Am I correct?

I run CoreNLP (in English) on a text containing a newline, but the result seems identical to the previous one. I called `isNewLine()` on every token, but none of them is `true`.

Is there any place where I can understand this new feature? Will it be used to mark newlines by adding a real token? Does it mean that counting tokens (for example using `annotation.get(CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation.class).size()`) will give a number that is not related to "real" tokens?

Comment: I tried this code:
`String sentenceText = "Barack Obama was the President of the United States.\nHe was very cool.";`
`Properties properties = new Properties();`
`properties.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize");`
`properties.setProperty("tokenize.keepeol", "true");`
`properties.setProperty("tokenize.whitespace", "true");`
`StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(properties);`
`Annotation annotation = new Annotation(sentenceText);`
`pipeline.annotate(annotation);`
There is a non-numered token after "States.", but `isNewLine()` on it is false.